# CMake - how to add a missing library easily?

Tags: powershell, cmake, darknet, vcpkg, cmake-gui

I'm trying to install Darknet from here https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet using these instructions:

https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet#how-to-compile-on-windows-using-cmake

Looked easy enough, I installed all the required pre-requisites...

I get the error "Could NOT find JPEG (missing: JPEG_LIBRARY JPEG_INCLUDE_DIR)" with CMake, I had an error like it before for Zlib, which I was able to install using this .bat file https://github.com/horta/zlib.install/blob/master/install.bat

What is the simplest way to include this library called' JPEG' within Cmake's scope of libraries?

Comment: So, do you have JPEG library installed? If not, you need to install it. E.g. via vcpkg.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Windows, the easiest way to manage C++ dependencies, *by far*, is [vcpkg](https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg). Follow the directions on their repo to install:

> ```console
> > git clone https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg
> > .\vcpkg\bootstrap-vcpkg.bat
> ```

Then install libjpeg as well as any other dependencies:

```console
> .\vcpkg\vcpkg install libjpeg libjpeg-turbo:x64-windows
```

If you need 32-bit, install `libjpeg-turbo:x86-windows` additionally (or instead).

Then, when trying to build Darknet, configure CMake with:

```console
> cmake -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=X:/path/to/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake ...
```

---

On the other hand, vcpkg has a darknet port, so you could just run:

```
> .\vcpkg\vcpkg install darknet[full]:x64-windows
```

Doesn't answer the question you asked, but maybe it's what you want, anyway.

Comment: Thanks so much, I was really struggling to find what the 'JPEG' library was called or where to get it from, your solution worked for me thankyou! I actually hit this error as something went wrong with vcpkg installing dependencies also but I couldn't reproduce that as a bug when I went back to do it again luckily.

Comment: Glad I could help!